# rake db:migrate creates a development.sqlite3 file that is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, railstutorial.org

I am learning ruby on rails following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.

I am stuck in this issue that occurred when I ran bundle exec db:migrate, as expected, a development.sqlite3 file was created in my /db folder.

So I tried to open that development.sqlite3 file using Sqlite Database Browser and it kept saying it was an invalid file. Tried to open it in other browsers and same thing... so apparently I am doing something wrong but cant find a workaround.

Here are some hints that might help a more experienced developer find the cause.

First of all I am using posgresql since thats what's recommended when you deploy on heroku. 
My database.yml file looks like this:

```
development:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: sampleapp_dev
    pool: 5
    username: *****
    password: *****
    min_messages: WARNING
    host: localhost
    port: ****
  test:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: sampleapp_test
    pool: 5
    username: ****
    password: ****
    min_messages: WARNING
    host: localhost
    port: ****
  production:
    adapter: postgresql
    database: sampleapp_live
    username: ****
    password: ****
    host: localhost
    port: ****
```

This is what the console showed when I ran rake db:migrate

```
\sample_app>bundle exec rake db:migrate

  ←[1m←[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "schema_mi
grations".* FROM "schema_migrations"←[0m
Migrating to CreateUsers (20140902194830)
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  BEGIN
==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
-- create_table(:users)
  ←[1m←[36m (159.1ms)←[0m  ←[1mCREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "n
ame" character varying(255), "email" character varying(255), "created_at" timest
amp, "updated_at" timestamp) ←[0m
   -> 0.1601s
==  CreateUsers: migrated (0.1619s) ===========================================

  ←[1m←[35mSQL (3.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES (
$1)  [["version", "20140902194830"]]
  ←[1m←[36m (17.7ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "schema_migrat
ions".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

I am pretty lost here, I dont see any errors, however when I try to open the .sqlite3 file to see that it has the columns I expect it to have, this message pops up: **"Invalid File Format"**

Has anyone had a similar issue or has an idea to solve this problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please use it to browse your database http://sqlitebrowser.org/

Comment: @Rajarshi-Das Yep.. sqlite browser is exactly what I am using (I tried to post a picture, but I dont have enough reputation yet)... and it says its an invalid file format.

Comment: you are using `postgresql ` why then you use sqlite3 file open use `pgadmin3` to browse postgresql database

Comment: Thanks @RajarshiDas! The problem is I cannot find the database in postgresql. Since what rails creates is a .sqlite3 file. PgadminIII wont open the development.sqlite3 file that was created when I ran db:migrate

Comment: Your `database.yml` is configured for postgres not sqlite. use postgres commands to see your database on console. try run `rails db` to see your db on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database.yml is configured for postgres not sqlite3. So your database is present in postgres.

If you are able to run `rake db:migrate` properly that means you have correct database configuration. Run `rails db` on console to explore your database.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I had to first configure posgresql PATH variable and then ran rails db and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!